# Exc_Bad_Access only sometimes on showing alert view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uialertview

I have many threads calling the following function by performSeleactoreOnMainThread method:

```
-(void) showAlert: (NSString *)message{
if ([NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] != [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]) {
    NSLog(@"<< perform in main thread>>");
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlert:) withObject:message waitUntilDone:NO];
}
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Info" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
}
```

As, in any case, this method will be called only on main thread, I am not getting the reason for EXC_BAD_ACCESS crash on the line: 
      [alert show]

And this crash comes only sometimes. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you forgot to add `return;` in your code so that your code below the if are also executed no matter it is in main loop or not.

a simple fix may be:

```
-(void) showAlert: (NSString *)message{
    if ([NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] != [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]) {
        NSLog(@"<< perform in main thread>>");
        [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlert:) withObject:message waitUntilDone:NO];
        return;
    }
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Info" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
    [alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue is due to whether the if condition is true or false the alertview displaying method will work.
Change your method like:

```
-(void) showAlert: (NSString *)message
{
 if ([NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] != [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop])
 {
    NSLog(@"<< perform in main thread>>");
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlert:) withObject:message waitUntilDone:NO];
 }
 else
 {
   UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Info" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
  [alert show];
 }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Put a `return` at the end of the if block:

```
-(void) showAlert: (NSString *)message{
if ([NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] != [NSRunLoop mainRunLoop]) {
    NSLog(@"<< perform in main thread>>");
    [self performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(showAlert:) withObject:message waitUntilDone:NO];
    return;
}
UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc]initWithTitle:@"Info" message:message delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil];
[alert show];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternative Why don't u use this:

```
 [alert performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(show) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
```

instead of

```
 [alert show];
```